# Can't Understand why "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"
```

This is the error i get  for no reason at all. i mean earlier it used to work but now it isnt.

In my code there is this website : https://www.tempinbox.xyz/
i open it using the chromedriver.
what i want to do is select (@fitschool.be) from the dropdown menu of domains.

and input some variable string which i have stored as variable "str(res)"

my code is:-

```
second_tab = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,)

    second_tab.get("https://www.tempinbox.xyz/")
    randombutton = second_tab.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/input[2]") #for the email generation
    randombutton.send_keys(str(res))
    mainurl = second_tab.current_url

    selectoption1=second_tab.find_element_by_id("selected-domain").click()
    selectoption2=second_tab.find_element_by_css_selector(".domain-selector:nth-child(3)").click()

    clickfinal= second_tab.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Create']").click()
    emailentry = str(res)+ "@fitschool.be"

    print ("your email is " + emailentry)
```

but it's giving me errors....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\AccountChef\wattpad acc maker.py", line 45, in <module>
    selectoption2=second_tab.find_element_by_css_selector(".domain-selector:nth-child(3)").click()
  File "C:\Users\BRS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\BRS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\BRS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\BRS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

pls suggest some changes and why this is happening. Thanks :)

Comment: hey can you give explain much more you need to click drop down then do you need click create button and send keys ?

Comment: click drop down then click on "@fitschool.be", then input text in that box and  click on submit button @Justin-Lambert

Comment: input into which box ?dont click create button ?

Comment: input into "Enter email id" box. i need to input some string value which is stored in a variable called str(res) @Justin-Lambert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the following two lines:

```
selectoption1=second_tab.find_element_by_id("selected-domain").click()
selectoption2=second_tab.find_element_by_css_selector(".domain-selector:nth-child(3)").click()
```

Try to set the innerHTML value with `.execute_script`:

```
element = second_tab.find_element_by_id("selected-domain")
target = "@fitschool.be"
second_tab.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '{}';".format(target), element)
```